# I can't update a SQL table with right concatenation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could you help me to concatenate in a good way ? I tried but I wasn't able to make it!

Here's my code :

```
include('config.php');

$base="recettes";

$sql="INSERT INTO". $base." (username, titre)  SELECT '$username', '$output[0]' ";
$request = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at your errors?  Did you try to output what `$sql` is  and try to run that command manually?

Comment: I think you're right ! Lemme check again...

Comment: My original point was that you didn't do basic debugging . . . first thing to do would have been to check the errors, and then work backwords, checking the SQL, etc, and there's no evidence you did any of that . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the concatenation... You're missing a space behind INTO and before ($username

When I have a query error, I always echo the query to see what it looks like.